how to get unattended-upgrade to obey apt pinned packages?
the unattended-upgrade package which is useful for keeping in sync with security updates, seems to override pinned packages, thereby breaking my system regularly, and me having to uninstall it (thereby making my system less secure).
I see this with the firefox package.  I am trying to use the package from mozilla and have it pinned as such, to not use the snap package.  It regularly gets "upgraded" (due to epoch) to the snap package, it took me a while to figure out why, but figured it out via history.log
Start-Date: 2024-05-16  10:19:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (125.0.3~build1, 1:1snap1-0ubuntu5)
End-Date: 2024-05-16  10:19:07

Start-Date: 2024-05-29  06:39:37
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: firefox:amd64 (126.0~build2, 1:1snap1-0ubuntu5)
End-Date: 2024-05-29  06:39:38

apt/aptitude don't have this problem as they obey my pins, but unattended-upgrade does not.
Package: *
Pin: origin packages.mozilla.org
Pin-Priority: 1000


Does this answer your question? How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?

Did you create the file /etc/apt/preferences.d/mozilla-firefox as instructed in the above linked Q&A?

Look at the line echo 'Unattended-Upgrade::Allowed-Origins:: "LP-PPA-mozillateam:${distro_codename}";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/51unattended-upgrades-firefox in the accepted answer.

add the -1 pin.  All those steps just show that unattended-upgrades is broken.  unattended-upgrades should a) pick packages that should be upgraded (based on their pinned values) and then filter based on origin information.  It shouldn't ignore pins that exist for a non upgraded origin.
I have to believe Canonical knows this and doesn't care as they want to force snap usages on people.

It's an unfixed bug in unattended-upgrades:

https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/319
https://github.com/mvo5/unattended-upgrades/issues/368
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/2033646

The proper workaround is to allow all origins (repositories) for automatic upgrades:
/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99unattended-upgrades-custom:
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
    "origin=*";
};

Which may probably be what you want anyway.
